# Same trend of datasets in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, trend

Imagine I have the following data set :

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║    ║ A          ║ B           ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 0.723185   ║ 0.216422    ║
║ 2  ║ 0.725254   ║ 0.216104    ║
║ 3  ║ 0.725166   ║ 0.214883    ║
║ 4  ║ 0.730094   ║ 0.22244     ║
║ 5  ║ 0.730336   ║ 0.222342    ║
║ 6  ║ 0.727938   ║ 0.21453     ║
║ 7  ║ 0.728334   ║ 0.217435    ║
║ 8  ║ 0.729766   ║ 0.21452     ║
║ 9  ║ 0.724968   ║ 0.213434    ║
║ 10 ║ 0.724352   ║ 0.214565    ║
║ 11 ║ 0.727014   ║ 0.2212523   ║
║ 12 ║ 0.731524   ║ 0.22845     ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

How can I test if A and B have the same trend? Is the [Jonckheere's trend test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonckheere%27s_trend_test) really the test I am looking for? I have found [this documentation](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/SAGx/html/JT.test.html) but how would it be in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site.  The answer depends on what you mean by "same trend". Just looking at the data, there doesn't seem to be much of a trend in either A or B.

The first thing I'd do here is plot the data:

```
time <- 1:12
A <- c(0.723185, 0.725254, 0.725166, 0.730094, 0.730336,  0.727938,
       0.728334, 0.729766, 0.724968, 0.724352, 0.727014, 0.731524)
B <- c(0.216422, 0.216104, 0.214883, 0.22244, 0.222342, 0.21453,
       0.217435, 0.21452, 0.213434, 0.214565, 0.2212523, 0.22845 )

plot(B~time, ylim = c(0,1), type = 'b')
points(x = time, y = A)
lines(x = time, y = A)
```

which again looks line two horizontal lines. But, following Cleveland's advice, it might be better to plot the difference or the ratio, e.g.

```
diff = B-A
plot(diff~time, type = 'b')
```

which does show some thing happening, but whether it has any meaning is impossible to tell without context.

There's more you could do, too, but that should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Peter. By "the same trend" I mean whether they are similar enough in their curve progression (e.g. same ups and downs, same gradient). I am not sure if there is a test which compares to data sets regarding their "ups and downs" and "gradients". An example: the curves y=4x^2+10 and y=4x^2-100 would have the "same trend" as their min and max and gradient is similar (in this case even equal), although their y coordinates are never identical.

Comment: @TuncJamgocyan It sounds like you want to test correlation?

Comment: I've thought about if the correlation test would be what I am looking for but I wasn't sure whether it was the right choice to test the similarity/trend of the above A and B...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your actual research question is, but I believe that the question stated in the comments ('compares to [sic] data sets regarding their "ups and downs"'), can be answered by testing the correlation.

```
cor.test(A,B)

     Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  A and B 
t = 3.0156, df = 10, p-value = 0.01299
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1924467 0.9054224 
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.6901269
```

You could also look at Spearman-correlation:

```
cor.test(A,B,method="spearman")

    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  A and B 
S = 122, p-value = 0.05548
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0 
sample estimates:
      rho 
0.5734266
```

Better advise could probably be given with more information and a clear statement of a hypothesis or research question.